# The conjunction "autem" expressing indignation or surprise in questions and exclamations

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, conjunction

When "autem" expresses this, it means "and, then, indeed"
The example from OLD: "quid tu autem? Etiam huic credis?" Pl. Capt.556
How can we translate it in a modern way?I'm asking because the translation in Portuguese is really weird. I never heard of it my entire life. I just wanted a better explanation from a native of English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would translate *autem* here as "too" or "even". Aristophontes here is shocked that Hegio seems to be believing Tyndarus's lies: "what, even you? You believe this too?" Or perhaps: "What, you too? You also believe this?"

Fundamentally it's an intensifier, which doesn't add much to the meaning but emphasizes the already-prominent *tu*. Aristophontes was already shocked to hear what Tyndarus is saying about him; he's then even *more* shocked that Hegio seems to be going along with it.